# objective c Core Data - Attributes aren't saved persistent

Tags: objective-c

i need help!!!^^

I write in my attributes (name,prename) the two names of the person and save them. If i try to access the attrubutes in another view then they are nil. I don't understand why?!?

I did it this way. I get the profileContext with the method getProfile and i access the Attributes with the Dot-Notation, then i save it. My NSLog show me the right name and my fetch too.

```
ownProfile = [[MyProfile alloc] init];
profileContext = [ownProfile getProfile];
ownProfile = (MyProfile*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyProfile" inManagedObjectContext:profileContext];
ownProfile.Vorname = @"Max";
ownProfile.Nachname = @"Wilson";
NSLog(@"%@",ownProfile.Nachname);



if ([profileContext hasChanges]) {
    NSLog(@"It has changes!");
    [profileContext save:nil];
}

//Fetching  
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyProfile" inManagedObjectContext:profileContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];

NSArray *array = [profileContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
for (int i=0; i < [array count]; i++) {
    MyProfile *object = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"Name: %@",object.Nachname);
}
```

if i try to access the attributes in another ViewController subclass they are nil. This is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

ownProfile = [[MyProfile alloc] init];
NSManagedObjectContext *profileContext = [ownProfile getProfile];
ownProfile = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyProfile" inManagedObjectContext:profileContext];

NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyProfile" inManagedObjectContext:profileContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];
[request setIncludesPropertyValues:NO]; //only fetch the managedObjectID

NSArray *array = [profileContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
[request release];
MyProfile *object = [array objectAtIndex:[array count]-1];
NSLog(@"%@",object);
```

}

my getProfile method is in the NSManagedObjectClass and look like this:

```
-(NSManagedObjectContext*) getProfile {


NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                         NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                         NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];


NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
NSLog(@"basePath = %@",basePath);
NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[basePath stringByAppendingFormat:@"CoreData.sqlite"]];
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil]];
NSLog(@"PersistentStore = %@",persistentStoreCoordinator);
NSError *error = nil;

if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"error loading persistent store..");
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:storeUrl.path error:nil];
    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}

NSManagedObjectContext *profile = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[profile setPersistentStoreCoordinator:persistentStoreCoordinator];


return profile;
```

}

Please help me!!!^^

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys...I solved my problem!!! :)

My fault was that I add in the viewDidLoad-Method in the line

```
ownProfile = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyProfile" inManagedObjectContext:profileContext];
```

another object in the persistentStore and i was always reading the new object where the attributes are nil...of course^^